# Nothing to repeat at position 0 when replacing string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In my MySQL database, phone in a VARCHAR. Then, I import this to a pandas dataframe. Here's my data:

```
data5

id   phone
1     +62634783472
2       0834838483
3              +62
```

What I want is convert +62 to 0, expected output would be like this

```
id   phone
1       0634783472
2       0834838483
3                0
```

I already try two thing, there are

```
data5['phone'] = data5['phone'].str.replace('+62', '0')

data5['phone'] = data5['phone'].replace(to_replace='+62', value='0', regex=True)
```

And the result is:

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

What is I miss?

Comment: `to_replace='\+62'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`+` is a special character and you have to escape it with `\`:

```
import pandas as pd
data5 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3], 
                      "phone": ["+62634783472", "0834838483", "+62"]})

data5['phone'] = data5['phone'].str.replace('\+62', '0')

# data5
   id       phone
0   1  0634783472
1   2  0834838483
2   3           0
```

Answer (score 1):

`replace` and `regex=True`

```
data5.replace({'\+62':'0'},regex=True)
Out[76]: 
   id       phone
0   1  0634783472
1   2  0834838483
2   3           0
```